# How to concatenate strings from a data frame while grouping, filtering, and ordering in R

Tags: r, concatenation, filtering, grouping

I am trying to use R to create a string that orders items by entry order for a particular session id so that i end up with something along the lines of:

| Session | convo_path |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Item1_Item2_Item5_Item8 |
| 1002 | Item1_Item4_Item6 |

Here is the code I am using to create the data frame and try to create the above result, as well as the result I am getting.

```
ex_data <- data.frame(
  Session.ID = c(1001,1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1003,1004,1004,1004,1004,1005,1005,1005,1005,1005),
  Entry.Order = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),
  Item.Name = c("Item1","Item2","Item5","Item8","Item1","Item4","Item6","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item9","Item11","Item4","Item6","Item1","Item2","Item5","Item8","Item1","Item9","Item7","Item8","Item10")
  )
ex_data

paths <- ex_data %>% 
group_by(Session = ex_data$Session.ID) %>% 
summarise(convo_path = paste(ex_data$Item.Name[order(ex_data$Entry.Order)], collapse = "_"))

paths
```

The above code is resulting in:

A tibble: 5 × 2

Session convo_path
1    1001 Item1_Item1_Item2_Item1_Item1_Item2_Item4_Item3_Item2_Item9_Item5_Item6_Item4_Item5_Item7_Item8_Item…
2    1002 Item1_Item1_Item2_Item1_Item1_Item2_Item4_Item3_Item2_Item9_Item5_Item6_Item4_Item5_Item7_Item8_Item…
3    1003 Item1_Item1_Item2_Item1_Item1_Item2_Item4_Item3_Item2_Item9_Item5_Item6_Item4_Item5_Item7_Item8_Item…
4    1004 Item1_Item1_Item2_Item1_Item1_Item2_Item4_Item3_Item2_Item9_Item5_Item6_Item4_Item5_Item7_Item8_Item…
5    1005 Item1_Item1_Item2_Item1_Item1_Item2_Item4_Item3_Item2_Item9_Item5_Item6_Item4_Item5_Item7_Item8_Item…

So, I am successfully building the concatenated items in order of entry order but the piece that seems to be missing is a way of filtering so only the items associated with Session ID 1001 are concatenated together then the ones associated with Session 1002 are concatenated together and so on.

I have tried a for loop as below:

```
paths <- ex_data %>% 
group_by(Session = ex_data$Session.ID) %>%
 for(i in Session.ID) {
summarise(convo_path = paste(ex_data$Item.Name[order(ex_data$Entry.Order)], collapse = "_"))
}

paths
```

which results in the following error:

> Error in for (. in i) Session.ID :    4 arguments passed to 'for'
> which requires 3

I have also tried filter in multiple spots:

Before summarise:

```
paths <- ex_data %>% 
group_by(Session = ex_data$Session.ID) %>% 
filter(ex_data$Session.ID) %>% 
summarise(convo_path = paste(ex_data$Item.Name[order(ex_data$Entry.Order)], collapse = "_"))
paths
```

which results in:

> Error in `filter()`: ! Problem while computing `..1 = ex_data$Session.ID`. ✖ Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size
> 23. ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Session = 1001. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

in the summarise:

```
paths <- ex_data %>% 
group_by(Session = ex_data$Session.ID) %>%
 summarise(convo_path = paste(ex_data$Item.Name[filter(ex_data$Session.ID)|order(ex_data$Entry.Order)], collapse = "_"))
paths
```

which results in:

> Error in `summarise()`: ! Problem while computing `convo_path = paste(...)`. ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Session = 1001. Caused
> by error in `UseMethod()`: ! no applicable method for 'filter' applied
> to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')" Run
> `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I am at a loss as to how I can get the concatenated stings to be filtered so I only get the items associated with the particular session id concatenated together. Any thoughts? is there something I am missing or something I should be doing differently?

Comment: Try `ex_data %>% group_by(Session = Session.ID) %>% summarise(convo_path = paste(sort(unique(Item.Name)), collapse = "_"))`

Comment: If you need to filter as well `ex_data %>% filter(Session.ID %in% c(1001, 1002)) %>% group_by(Session = Session.ID) %>% summarise(convo_path = paste(sort(unique(Item.Name)), collapse = "_"))`

Answer (score 1):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
ex_data %>% 
  filter(Session.ID %in% c(1001, 1002)) %>% 
  group_by(Session = Session.ID) %>%
  summarise(convo_path = paste(sort(unique(Item.Name)), collapse = "_"))
```